# What kind of hash is this?

Tags: hash, sha-256

I am doing some penetration testing and I found this potentially predictable URL being used for password resets and although it says it uses SHA-256 for the hash I'm not sure that it does because the hash when URL decoded is 44 characters long and SHA-256 hashes are always 64 characters long. My second guess was that it was a SHA-256 digest that is Base64 encoded but that yielded non-printable characters that wouldn't be found as an output from a SHA-256 hash (or any other hash to my knowledge). The URL/Query string is here (Some parts are replaced with X as this is a potentially vulnerable page):
https://XXX.XXXXXXX.XX/UpdatePassword.aspx?token=userid%3DXXXXXX-tfhs%252FXXXX.XXXXXXXX%2540XXXXXX.XXX%26timestamp%3D2016-10-25T21%253A20%253A12.8771033Z%26algorithm%3DSHA256%26hash%3DHoeica3NlXm2MNEbej34uMcQ0Y%252BDMM9o08HDIRP6mz8%253D

Can anyone help me determine how the hash is generated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cryptographic hash function produces uniformly distibuted *binary* data (not 64 characters). 256 bits of *binary* data base64 encoded is 43 characters without padding. When base64 decoded, SHA-256 output would almost certainly contain zero bytes and other "unprintable characters".

I suspect you have a SHA-256 hash on your hands, just like it says on the query string. But it could be an HMAC construction using SHA-256, or an application constant "pepper" could be used when generating the hash output. Or the "algorithm" parameter could be an obfuscation and something completely different is in use.